# Is there a way to return multiple values using for range in render_template flask

Tags: python, flask, data-science

I've created a program that iterates 4 array values with its respective recalls,
also using shuffle function to dynamically shuffle them every time it execute.

```
def predict_IT():
    new_Xdata_IT = X_IT.sample(5)
    new_Ydata_IT = Cat_Y[new_Xdata_IT.index.values]
    pred_IT = model_IT.predict(new_Xdata_IT)

    def recall(new_Ydata_IT, pred_IT, K):
            act_set = set(new_Ydata_IT)
            pred_set = set(pred_IT[:K])
            result = round(len(act_set & pred_set) / float(len(act_set)), 2)
            return result

    actual = new_Ydata_IT
    prediction = np.array(["Software Engineer / Programmer", "Technical Support Specialist", "Academician", "Administrative Assistant"])
    np.random.shuffle(prediction)
    
    def returnResult():
        output = []
        for K in range(0, 4):
            output.append(f"{prediction[K]} = {recall(actual, prediction, K)}")
            return output
        
    return render_template("predictIT.html", prediction_text = returnResult())
```

It successfully return the first index but the remaining 3 values won't come after. I suspect the render_template function doesn't allow any iterations to be passed if so is there any other way for me to iterate the given array. any respond is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are immediately returning in the for loop. Take the return out of the for loop and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @BcK it returns None